# FIFO / QUEUE with buffer and thread-safe

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm receiving tons of statistics data that I need to insert into the db.
I would like to implement some kind of Queue or FIFO class that keeps all the data
and when it reaches to a specific count (buffer), it will send that data to the SQL through bulk insert. This should be thread-safe.

I know how to make the bulk insert.
Any advices how to make the queue / list?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running under .Net 4?

Answer (score 2):

The .net base class library has `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)` . Just import `System.Collections.Concurrent`.

*Edit*: If you must use a queue, you could create a wrapper class/module that fires off an event when the counter (buffer) reaches a certain amount.

Comment: What about a call-back function when you reach the buffer limit and have it as threadsafe?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need strict FIFO I think you should use `BlockingCollection`.

It is thread safe and the implementation would look somthing like:

```
var collection = new BlockingCollection<Data>();

var sqlinserter = Task.Factory.StartNew(UpdateSql());

while (true) {
    Data statistics = FetchStatistics();
    if (statistics == null)
        break;
    collection.Add(statistics);
}
collection.CompleteAdding();
sqlinserter.Wait();
```

**Edit**
Saw that you wanted to  insert a specific count of items in each batch

```
void UpdateSql() {
    var batch = new List<Data>();
    foreach (var item in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        batch.Add(item);
        if (batch.Count > SomeBatchSize) {
            InsertIntoSql(batch);
            batch.Clear();
        }
    }
    if (batch.Count > 0)
        InsertIntoSql(batch); // insert remaining items
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a safe way to deal with it.
Primarily you want to avoid any situation where you can get "stuck" inside a synclock.

```
Public Class TSQueue(Of T)

    Private q As New Queue(Of T)
    Public Property threshold As Integer = 100
    Public Event ThresholdHit As EventHandler(Of EventArgs)

    Public Sub EnqueueSafe(value As T)
        Dim notify As Boolean = False
        SyncLock q
            q.Enqueue(value)
            If q.Count >= threshold Then
                notify = True
            End If
        End SyncLock
        If notify Then
            RaiseEvent ThresholdHit(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function DequeueSafe() As T
        SyncLock q
            Return q.Dequeue()
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Function DequeueAllSafe() As T()
        Dim out() As T
        SyncLock q
            out = q.ToArray()
            q.Clear()
        End SyncLock
        Return out
    End Function

    Public Function CountSafe() As Integer
        SyncLock q
            Return q.Count
        End SyncLock
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is not the answer since the question was effectively "...implement some kind of Queue or FIFO class that keeps all the data and when it reaches to a specific count (buffer), it will send that data to the SQL through bulk insert. This should be thread-safe. Any advices how to make the queue / list?" the event ThresholdHit would trigger the dump of the data and the background queue is threadsafe via the synclock statements.